# Mat-Calendar Custom Header should not change the activedate

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular's `mat-calendar` component and I'm currently working on customizing the UI and handling the month change event. To achieve this, I'm utilizing the "Custom Header" feature, as described in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header).

Now the issue is it's changing the calendar's `activeDate`, which is kind of a hack to change the view of the month as I wanted to just change the month view and not actual selection. The implementation for the default header month view change is correct, as it's not updating the `activeDate` and just changing the month view.

```
    nextClicked() {
        this._calendar.activeDate = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarMonths(this._calendar.activeDate, 1)
    }
```

Is there a way to move between month views without updating the `activeDate`, just like the default header does?